# Ansible : how to pass "{{ABC}}" as a string

Tags: ansible, jinja2, ansible-2.x, ansible-template

Under my jinja file i ve this line

```
- mockString= "{{ABC}}"
```

My mockString must have the exacte value **"{{ABC}}"** where the first letter is **"** , the second is **{** the third is also **{**  ect...

Now when converting my template file ; it seems that i sees **"{{ABC}}"** as a variable , where it tries to interpret and change by its value , what is not my purpose.

How may i pass it as a simple string

**Suggestions ??**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try passing it like this `{{'"{{ABC}}"'}}` this should work

Comment: this have passed only this {{ABC}}  , commas " haven't been passed

Comment: Then try this one `{{'"{{asd}}"'}}`

Answer (score 0):

you can try like this :

```
  mockString= \"{{ACB}}\"
```

Comment: i'm inside a jinja file

Comment: Should be the same with the "\" ?